# Wrap an OCaml function that returns a record

Tags: js-of-ocaml, ocsigen

I have defined an OCaml function `manipulate: string -> string`. And I wrap it to make a JS function `jsManipulate`:

```
let () =
  Js.Unsafe.global##.jsManipulate := Js.wrap_callback
      (fun s -> Js.string (manipulate (Js.to_string s)))
```

Now, I want to make `manipulate` return more information than just a string; I want it to return a record: `manipulate: string -> myrecord` where `myrecord = { result: string; info_1: int; info_2: bool }` in OCaml format.

In this case, does anyone know how to wrap `manipulate` to make a JS function that returns also a JS record (or object?) from a JS string?

PS: I want to call `manipulate` only one time (rather than 3 times) to build the JS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular javascript is not going to be able to understand OCaml's record, even when code is compiled in javascript with js_of_ocaml.

What you should use instead is a javascript object (There is no difference between a record and an object in javascript). You can read about creating literal objects at the bottom of this page: http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.7/api/Ppx_js

You can create a function `to_object` of type `myrecord -> < .. > Js.t` that returns an object. Then you can use it for wrapping instead of `Js.to_string`.